# Can anyone point out why the error is occuring? Error is "expected "=",";","asm" or __attribute__ before "<"

Tags: c, malloc

What I am trying to accomplish here is a dictionary with linked list. There is an array of node pointers. I am trying to initialize each array pointer using malloc. When I remove the for loop, it works fine.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int collisions = 0;
unsigned long index = 0;
#define HASHTABLE_SIZE 1999099

// Initialize struct for linked list.

typedef struct node{
     char word[46];
     struct node *next;
  } node;

// Initialize an array of node pointers.

node *hashtable[HASHTABLE_SIZE];


for(unsigned long i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
  //   Error here reads expected "=",";","asm" or __attribute__ before "<"

  {
    hashtable[i] = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

  }
```

Comment: Is all this in the same file? It's unclear since it's separated in your question.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-Wall`? Are you getting no other warnings?

Comment: I don't think that the code that you show us here shows your problem. And, BTW, don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Your "initialize" comments are incorrect.  You're declaring things, not initializing them.

Comment: @michael, Sorry for the confusion. Yes, its all in the same file as edited by keith.

Comment: @kevin, so the `for` loop isn't inside a function?

Comment: @Dan Fego, Nope, it was in another file. I completely missed that. Also is there any explanation for the error warning vs the error I just made. Being a noob, I would have checked for missing semicolons.

Comment: @JensGustedt, Is there any reason for not casting them?

Comment: @kevin, please have a look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statements are allowed only inside functions.

Add

```
int main(void) {
```

before the for loop, and

```
    return 0;
}
```

after it.  Or, if `main` is in another file, define some other function to contain the loop.

Comment: the main is in another file. Cannot add main here.

Comment: Whether the loop is in `main` or not, it has to be in *some* function.

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem.(although many more popped up now).I can see how it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `for(unsigned long i = 0; ...` construct is only valid in C99, my guess is that you're not compiling your code as C99 (or your compiler is not C99-compliant).

An easy way to check is by moving the declaration of `i` to the top of the enclosing code block.

I am assuming that what you're showing us in not the whole compilation unit, but excerpts from it. If the assumption is wrong, and the code you've shown resides outside all functions, then you need to enclose it in a function, as explained by @Keith Thompson.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for loops while declaring variables inside them you have to use the C99 standard. I don't know about other compilers but with gcc you'll need to pass the flag `--std=c99`.

This will compile for loops like the one you have:

```
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should read

```
node *hashtable[HASHTABLE_SIZE];
unsigned long i;

for(i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
  //   Error here reads expected "=",";","asm" or __attribute__ before "<"

  {
    hashtable[i] = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

  }
```

You cannot declare a variable inside a `for()` in C, only in C++ and (as @DonFego pointed out) in C99.

Comment: You can in C99. See aix's answer.

Comment: @DanFego Yeah, that's what I meant. I'll edit it, thank you! = )